# Referencing terraform remote state stored in gitlab does not work

Tags: terraform, gitlab

In my EKS configuration terraform. I'm referencing a remote state for a VPC project as such:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "http"
  config = {
    address = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<ID 1>/terraform/state/${var.env}"
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.  
╷  
│ Error: HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth
```

The gitlab CI seems to run fine and resources are appropriately created, however, running `terraform plan` does not work locally.

Using this provided by gitlab:

```
$ terraform init \  
    -backend-config="address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<ID 2>.../dev
    -backend-config="password=$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
...
```

my suspicion is that I'm somehow scoped to the ID 2 state and unable to reference the ID 1 from the remote state resource, but only locally...

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your suspicion may be the underlying issue here, given the error you're receiving it looks like even if you're adding credentials to your Terraform state, those are not added to the remote backend and so it's failing to fetch data.

You can try to add this information to your `remote_state` block and see if it works (it should):

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "http"
  config = {
    address = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<ID 1>/terraform/state/${var.env}"
    username = var.gitlab-username
    password = var.gitlab-access-token
  }
}
```

The difference on running this on the CI is that GitLab correctly fills the backend `http` information (like the `username` and `password`) automatically, opposed to the local env.